# Как Правильно указать путь к txt файлу в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброй ночи всем. Скажите пожалуйста как **Правильно** указать путь к `SomeText.txt` файлу в Unity? Чтобы после создания .Apk файла все также корректно работала,как и в редакторе.

Вот варианты которые я пробовал:

```
//1.
String FileRoud = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/StreamingAssets/SomeText.txt";
//2.
String FileRoud = "Assets/Resources/SomeText.txt";
//3.
var t = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("SomeText.txt");
```

Эти три варианта не работают у меня.

Comment: ну собери апк и протестируй)

Comment: 3 вариант наименее захардкожен, засим, если он работает- лучше его использовать в виду меньшей возможности багов из-за опечаток.

Comment: Если хотя бы один из этих вариантов работали бы  после сборки апк файла я бы не стал писать вопрос .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для мобильных устройств нужно использовать StreamingAssets. Но разница не только в путях но и использовании, там нужна корутина c запросом через `WWW` класс [Using Streaming Assets in Unity](https://www.raywenderlich.com/479-using-streaming-assets-in-unity).

Для `.txt` есть простой вариант указания его как поля класса типа `TextAsset` в какой нибудь `Prefab` или `ScriptableObject`.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить второй вариант по подробнее.Я  в юнити новичок.С этим я уже мучаюсь второй день.

Comment: `public TextAsset myTxt;` это называется поле класса, не переменная. `Unity3d` тут вообще не причем, это `C#`.

Comment: А как потом это поле класса myTxt  передать в качестве string path в   File.ReadAllLines(string path)                                                                                                                                                             .
int CountLines = File.ReadAllLines(FileRoud).Length;

Comment: Какой path? зачем? это уже файл! Погули, какие поля и методы класса `Unity3d TextAsset`. Погугли методы класса `C# File`, если он тебе вообще нужен.

Comment: Yaroslav, Спасибо вам.Сделал  по другому.Всё работает.Этот вопрос оставит или удалить лучше?

Comment: @Mura можно просто отметить ответ галочкой.